# Calling a recursive lambda expression

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have this function here which sends a request

```kotlin
fun request(requestCode: Int, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    val result = false
    // Some job...
    callback(result)
}
```

apparently, this function takes a lambda expression as an argument.
Now, when I need to call this function from the main function I have this scenario where if the callback result is true I need to do some job, and otherwise, I need to repeat the request again.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    request(10) { result ->
        if (result) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Here I need to make the request again
            request(10) { result2 ->
                // And so on..
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem now is that I need to repeat the call indefinitely!!.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is, just call `main`! Since `main` calls `request` immediately, calling `main` will call `request`:

```
fun main() {
    request(10) { result ->
        if (result) {
            // Success
        } else {
            main()
        }
    }
}
```

If you have other code before `request` in `main`, simply call `request` in a function that *does* call `request` immediately:

```
fun requestUntilSuccess() {
    request(10) { result ->
        if (result) {
            // success
        } else {
            requestUntilSuccess()
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    // some other code...

    requestUntilSuccess()
}
```

However, it will do this forever if the request keeps failing. You might want to add a `maxTries` parameter:

```
fun requestUntilSuccess(maxTries: Int) {
    if (maxTries == 0) {
        // out of tries
        return
    }
    request(10) { result ->
        if (result) {
            // success
        } else {
            requestUntilSuccess(maxTries - 1)
        }
    }
}
```